# FlatList not displaying with fetched json object

Tags: facebook, react-native

I'm currently following [Facebook's React Native Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) and I'm having trouble fetching a json object from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json and displaying it in a FlatList. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {FlatList, ActivityIndicator, ListView, View } from 'react-native';
import { Card, CardItem, Text, Container, Header, Title, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Left, Right, Body, Icon } from 'native-base';

class JobPost extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <Card>
          <CardItem header>
              <Text>{this.props.header}</Text>
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem>
              <Body>
                  <Text>
                      {this.props.body}
                  </Text>
              </Body>
          </CardItem>
     </Card>
    )
  }
}

export default class Movies extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: ''
    }
  }



  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
        <FlatList
        data={this.state.dataSource}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Card header={item.title} body={item.releaseYear}/>}
        keyExtractor={item => item.title}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The console log to print out the json object works correctly. However, I just get a blank screen when I run it in the IOS Simulator.

Comment: Could you add some more detail? Did you try running the code w/o the server call? Does the flat list show up with dummy data?

Comment: I think it's because of your renderItem prop. Try logging the `item` param and see if you're calling the object correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was it wasn't retrieving an array from the fetch, so I was supposed to specify `dataSource: responseJson.movies`

That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Flat list will not update date if you don't set `extraData`.
You should use extraData for Flat list if want to update `data` (`extraData={this.state}    ): https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.48/flatlist.html#extradata